# Can't mount Windows shares by name, only IP

Tags: windows, linux, samba

I'm mounting a Windows share using the following in Ubuntu:

```
mount -t cifs username=MYUSER,password=1234 //192.168.1.5/myshare /mnt/windows_share
```

This works fine, but I would like to mount the share using the computer's hostname, not the IP.

I can ping the hostname fine, but I mounting using the hostname instead of the IP does not work. The share cannot be found.

In Windows, I can access the share as `\\COMPUTER\\\myshare`, and using Nautilus in Ubuntu, I can connect to `//COMPUTER/myshare`, but I can't use the name in the mount command.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have `mount.cifs` installed on your system? From the [CIFS User Guide](http://pserver.samba.org/samba/ftp/cifs-cvs/linux-cifs-client-guide.pdf):

> Once the CIFS VFS support is built
>   into the kernel or installed as a
>   module (cifs.o), you can use mount
>   syntax like the following to access
>   Samba or Windows servers:
>
> `mount -t cifs //9.53.216.11/e$ /mnt -o user=myname,pass=mypassword`
>
> If the mount helper, **mount.cifs**, is installed
>   (which is usually the case for most
>   Linux distributions), then a tcp host
>   name rather than ip address may be
>   used.  For example,
>
> `mount -t cifs //my_server/e$ /mnt -o user=myname,pass=mypassword`

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, in ubuntu between 14.04 and 15.10, mount.cifs was not installed by default.  It can simply be added by installing package cifs-utils.  This resolved the issue for me.